# Keyboard backlight function keys for Samsung Series 9 np900x3d and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, samsung, backlight

I purchased a new Samsung New Series 9 NP900X3D and installed Ubuntu 13.10 tonight.  The keyboard illumination function keys do not work.  I've read on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SamsungSeries9 to edit the /lib/udev/keymaps files, however, these files do not exist in Ubuntu 13.10. How do I get the function keys for keyboard illumination to work properly for Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

in 13.10 you have to 
check your product

```
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name
  870Z5E/880Z5E/680Z5E
```

edit

```
vi /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb
```

and check/edit/add a lines like this

```
keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn[sS][aA][mM][sS][uU][nN][gG]*:pn*900X[34][CDG]*:pvr*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_97=!kbdillumdown                          # Fn+F9 keyboard backlight down
  KEYBOARD_KEY_96=!kbdillumup                            # Fn+F10 keyboard backlight up
```

and then

```
udevadm hwdb --update
```

But it seems to matter whether you installed ubuntu in EFI or in CMS/BIOS mode.
EFI-installed does not work even after those changes

Answer (score 0):

for 900x3a I had to edit:

```
# Series 9
keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn[sS][aA][mM][sS][uU][nN][gG]*:pn*90X3A*:pvr*
keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn[sS][aA][mM][sS][uU][nN][gG]*:pn*900X[34][AB]*:pvr*
KEYBOARD_KEY_96=!kbdillumup
KEYBOARD_KEY_97=!kbdillumdown
```

in:

```
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb
```

No idea why those were partially blank to begin with. Run

```
udevadm hwdb --update
```

and reboot. Cheers!